# KineticJS: Line.getPoints() method does not return an array of points. Why?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

The getPoints() method on a Line object in KineticJS does not return an array of points. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GW6SS/) illustrating the problem.

In the fiddle, I have placed a button that runs the `test()` function.

My code is as follows:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
container: 'main',
width: 1200,
height: 400,
});

var linesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var textLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var testLine = new Kinetic.Line({
     points: [100, 100, 100, 200],

    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 3});

linesLayer.add(testLine);

function test(){

var context = textLayer.getContext();
context.font = '18pt Calibri';
context.fillStyle = 'black';

context.fillText(testLine.getPoints().join(),100,350);

}
stage.add(linesLayer);

stage.add(textLayer);
```

The result displayed on the screen when the `test()` function runs is `[object Object],[object Object]` and I'm not sure why or how to deal with is. Help?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

in fact it does. It returns an array of two objects (as you could already see in your output), and everyone of these objects contains two values: x and y.

Here a screenshot of the console if you log testLine.getPoints():

[image]

Comment: How do I access these values in order to get them and also change them?

Comment: to get all x or y values, you can loop trough testLine.getPoints().length (`for(i=0;i<testLine.getPoints().length;i++)`) and return the x or y value by using `testLine.getPoints()[i].x`. Changing points works by using `testLine.setPoints()`